# Run PowerShell in Google Backup and Sync folder

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api

I installed Google Backup and Sync and placed my PowerShell script, `myscript.ps1`, within the Google Backup and Sync folder at `C:\Users\<username>\Google Drive`. When I double click `myscript.ps1`, the PowerShell window will open for a very brief period, then close without running. If I move `myscript.ps1` to any other location in my C:/ drive, I can double click it and it will run without problems. Also, if I open PowerShell and type `C:\Users\<username>\Google Drive\myscript.ps1` it also works without problems. It is just when I double left click within the Google Drive folder that I run into issues. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to log out and back into Google Drive/Sync.  This happened to me a while back and I am pretty sure that resolved it.

Comment: I tried this and still seem to be having the same problem.